# MySQL AES encryption based on Java function

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, aes

I have functions to encrypt and decrypt using Java.

```
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private static byte[] key;
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private final static String secretKey = "mySecretKey";

    public void prepareSecreteKey(String theKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = theKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            System.out.println(key.toString());
            secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String doEncrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            prepareSecreteKey(secretKey);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Wrong Secret key to do cipher!" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String doDecrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
        try {
            prepareSecreteKey(secretKey);
            String test = secretKeySpec.getFormat().toString();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Wrong Secret key to do cipher!" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

For the existing data in database, I wanted to encrypt using AES_encrypt mysql function. However, when I tried for the query below, it returns BLOB format instead of string.

```
select AES_encrypt('0121234566', 'mySecretKey')
```

I tried to run the query below but it returns null.

```
SELECT CAST(AES_encrypt('0121234566', 'mySecretKey') AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8);
```

Anyone can advise? Thanks.

Comment: Aes_encrypt returns a binary string, not a blob. How java interprets it is a different matter. You must not convert the results to a different character set as it will change the byte values preventing you from decrypting the data.

Comment: I don't understand why you would write any Java code at all, when you can use MySQL functions for it. `throw new SecurityException("Wrong Secret key to do cipher!"...` This is just a wild guess and it is bound to trip you or the user up sooner or later. You caught `Exception` when you threw this exception with this message. There are dozens if not hundreds of possible causes. Don't write code like this/